# Endomorphism $T$ on $\mathbb{C}^4$ whose charactersitic polynomial is $z(z-1)^3$ but $T(T-I)^2 \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Give an example of an endomorphism $\textsf{T}$ on $\mathbb{C}^4$ whose characteristic polynomial is $z(z-1)^3$ but $\textsf{T}(\textsf{T}-\textsf{I})^2 \neq 0$.

So I'm not very sure how to approach this.
I'm guessing $\textsf{T}$ is not nilpotent since its characteristic polynomial doesn't equal $z^4$. I'm not sure what the significance of $\textsf{T}(\textsf{T}-\textsf{I})^2 \neq 0$ is.

Can anyone give me a hand with how to approach this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Jordan Canonical Form?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious guess of a diagonal matrix with that characterstic polynomial does not satisfy the condition $T(T-I)^2\neq 0$. I recommend modifying some entries in such a diagonal matrix to obtain an upper triangular matrix that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jordan blocks for 0 and 1. Clearly the multiplicity of 0 is 1 and hence the Jordan block of 0 is $A=(0)$. Similarly the multiplicity of 1 is 3 and hence the Jordan block of 1 is $B=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&1&0\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&1
\end{matrix}\right)$.  Now putting them together, you have
$$ T=\left(\begin{matrix}A&0\\
0&B\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1
\end{matrix}\right). $$
It is easy to check that $T$ is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) to the polynomial.
$$
p(x) = x(x-1)^3 = x^4 - 3x^3 + 3x^2 - x
$$
So, we'd get
$$
T = \pmatrix
{
0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&-3\\
0&0&1&3
}
$$